# Office 365 Video - External Sharing

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, external-users

Is it possible to make Office 365 Video sharable outside organization? If so what is the configurations to be done on the office portal admin site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know its still not possible, but they [started working](https://office365video.uservoice.com/forums/273864-o365-video-feedback/suggestions/7644834-allow-external-sharing) on it in march.

> Started working on external sharing a channel with authenticated
>   users.

And tbh I'm not sure what will happen to O365 Video after they started working on [Stream](https://stream.microsoft.com/en-us/)

---

Comment from the Office 365 Team:

> Microsoft Stream builds upon the learnings and success of Office 365
>   Video, and over time the two experiences will converge, making Stream
>   the de facto video experience in Office 365.

Comment: i was also looking at the user vioce page. Was hoping that it wasn't up to date. Really need this in our enterprise portal. 

Thanks for the info, heard first time about Stream. Is Stream going to be under O365 subscription?

Comment: @bkk looks like they'll merge the video into stream overtime. Check this [post](https://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2016/07/18/introducing-microsoft-stream-the-secure-destination-to-manage-and-share-videos-for-businesses-of-all-sizes/#sm.0010emhmcrieeds10it1xf231v636) from Microsoft. So I'm guessing it will be available with the office 365 plan at some level.

Comment: Here is another comment from the office 365 team: _Microsoft Stream builds upon the learnings and success of Office 365 Video, and over time the two experiences will converge, making Stream the de facto video experience in Office 365._

Comment: The Public Videos idea, for Stream, has 140 votes and was marked as "planned" last month. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Stream-Ideas/Public-videos/idi-p/80159